# pandas set cell color with condition (in multi-index)

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I want to set color to particular element and write excel/html in pandas dataframe.

my data frame is :

```
  old                new            diff
  query result       query result   result
1 q1    a1           q1    a1       True
2 q2    a2           q2    a5       False
3 q3    a3           q3    a3       True
4 q4    a4           q4    a6       False
```

I want to highlight "False" data in `['diff']['result']` column when I write this dataframe to excel/html.

How can I highlighting cells?

Thanks

Comment: read this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change function  [`highlight_max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Building-styles), use [`Styler.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html) and for select `MultiIndex` column use tuple:

```
def coloring(val):
    color = 'red' if val is False else ''
    return 'color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(coloring, subset=[('diff','result')])
```

Comment: And Is there a method to apply this function .to_html method?

Comment: @sjpark - no, but if want render `html` only add `html = df.style.applymap(coloring, subset=[('diff','result')]).render()`

Comment: @Ambleu - Sure, change `color` to `background-color`

Comment: how to include index as subset? and does it now work on multiple sheet excel?

Comment: `and does it now work on multiple sheet excel` - No, you need processing each sheet separately.

Comment: @Ambleu - Is possible create new question?

Comment: Yup will do, thanks.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853841/using-df-style-applymap-to-color-cells-background-for-multiple-sheet-excel

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you could do.

```
def color_false_red(val):
    color = 'red' if val is False else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

and in your df

```
df.style.apply(color_false_red, subset=['diff'])
```

This would change the color of the text.