# using df.style.applymap to color cell's background for multiple sheet excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

MRE created with help from https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.05-hierarchical-indexing.html, amazing summary on Hierarchical indexing

MRE:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2013, 2014,2015, 2016]],
                                   names=['year'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Bob', 'Guido', 'Sue'], ['HR', 'group']])

data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,"g1"],
                 [3,6,1,3,2,"g2"],
                 [3,6,1,2,3,"g1"],
                 [6,7,8,11,23,"g2"]])

all_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
```

Using one df and coloring cell's background depending on condition works fine however when I try to apply it to multiple sheet excel it does not seems to work.

here is my code:

```
def coloring(val):
    color = '#EDFFE7' if val in lst else 'white'
    return f"background-color: {color}"


groups = ["g1", "g2"]
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
for g in groups:
    df = all_df.loc[all_df[("Sue","group")] == g].copy()
    df.style.applymap(coloring).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=g)
writer.save()
```

This

Also, how to add index for subset parameter in applymap method?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need chain both rows, because `df.style.applymap(coloring)` is not assigned back:

```
df.style.applymap(coloring).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=g)
```

instead:

```
df.style.applymap(coloring)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=g)
```

Or assign back:

```
df = df.style.applymap(coloring)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=g)
```

EDIT:

for me working well, if values in  list are integers, because if use `np.array` for mixed data - strings with numbers numpy convert all data to objects:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2013, 2014,2015, 2016]],
                                   names=['year'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Bob', 'Guido', 'Sue'], ['HR', 'group']])

data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,"g1"],
                 [3,6,1,3,2,"g2"],
                 [3,6,1,2,3,"g1"],
                 [6,7,8,11,23,"g2"]])

all_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

print (all_df.dtypes)

Bob    HR       object
       group    object
Guido  HR       object
       group    object
Sue    HR       object
       group    object
dtype: object
```

So if pass nested lists to `DataFrame` all working well for me:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2013, 2014,2015, 2016]],
                                   names=['year'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Bob', 'Guido', 'Sue'], ['HR', 'group']])

data = [[1,2,3,4,5,"g1"],
        [3,6,1,3,2,"g2"],
        [3,6,1,2,3,"g1"],
        [6,7,8,11,23,"g2"]]

all_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

print (all_df.dtypes)
Bob    HR        int64
       group     int64
Guido  HR        int64
       group     int64
Sue    HR        int64
       group    object
dtype: object
```

---

```
def coloring(val):
    color = '#EDFFE7' if val in lst else 'white'
    return f"background-color: {color}"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")

groups = ["g1", "g2"]
lst = [1,2,3]


for g in groups:
    df = all_df.loc[all_df[("Sue","group")] == g].copy()
    #print (df)
    df.style.applymap(coloring).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=g)

writer.save()
```

Comment: `df.style.applymap(coloring).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=g)` still doesn't seem to work. and tried assigning back method as well.

Comment: @Ambleu - Is possible create some data sample for test this?

Comment: hm... actually doing it on data I've just created works. The only different is that my original data is multiindex dataframe. Let me try to create multiindex MRE and try it.

Comment: I've updated my question with new MRE, sorry I had to learn how to create multiindex column dataframe.