# Conditional formatting of specific multi-indexed columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code, multi-index

How to apply conditional formatting (*highlight in yellow if value > 1.*), not over the whole table but only these 2 columns:

- "comparisonResult.NoMatch"
- "False"

I can only apply to the whole table.
[image]

I have this code:

```
styled_df = result.loc[:,idx[:,'ComparisonResult.NoMatch']]
                  .style.apply(lambda x : ['font-weight: bold; background-color: yellow' 
                                          if value >= 1 else '' for value in x])
```

But this basically leaves me with only my ComparisonResult.NoMatch Column as my result.

By the way, I am using Visual Studio Code, but I don't see very rich IntelliSense, for example pressing dot on the "value" field suggests nothing. Is something wrong with my extensions installation?

Comment: Please share your input as text.

Comment: You can get smart suggestions with `CTrl+Space`, check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues with your suggested code:**

- Indeed a `.loc` on the dataframe to be formatted will only limit your view, not select the region to apply format to.
- The origin and purpose of `idx` are unclear.

**This is what you need instead:**

```py
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['font-weight: bold; background-color: yellow' if value >= 1 else '' for value in x], 
               subset=[ ('Match','comparisonResult.NoMatch'), ('Match','False') ])
```

This uses the `subset` argument to `apply`, as suggested in

- [pandas set cell color with condition (in multi-index)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59781405/12846804)
- [Pandas style function to highlight specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41654949/12846804)

(It seems like `result` may be the name of your multi-index dataframe, prior to formatting, but I'm not sure. I've called it `df`. )

By the way, for easier reuse you may declutter like this:

```py
Import numpy as np

def highlighter(x):
    return np.where(x>=1, 'font-weight: bold; background-color: yellow', None)

df.style.apply(highlighter, 
               subset=[ ('Match','comparisonResult.NoMatch'),
                        ('Match','False') ])
```